# Blazor hosted debugger issue

Tags: blazor

I have been working for the past 3 months on a project that is based on Blazor hosted solution (API + Blazor web assembly )

everything was smooth until I formatted pc and reinstalled visual studio, now once I try to attach a debugger on the client-side of the solution I get the following error: a debugger operation is taking a long time to complete. Click "Cancel" to stop waiting and terminate the process.

I'm using the latest version of enterprise visual studio.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.vs .obj and .bin` folders?

Comment: Also make sure you are using the latest version of edge/chrome

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I end up having to kill Visual Studio from Task Manager because it gets stuck there

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue recently introduced into Resharper:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-483982

Workaround:
Disabling the following options:

ReSharper | Options | Debugger | Editor Integration | Show local variable values
ReSharper | Options | Debugger | Editor Integration | Show current line expressions values.

Answer (score 0):

The only correct way for me to fix this problem was to reinstall the complete system and install visual studio from zero.

Comment: Obviously you did something else, because you formatted and reinstalled the complete system the first time too. You must have done something different the first time. Did you install some extension like Resharper the first time? Was there any change in the settings?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had ReSharper both times installed. The point is in the newest installation I only selected the ASP.NET Core package, and nothing else, in the previous one where I had a problem with debugging I did select many other things such as debugging, etc and I believe the problem was in that one.

Answer (score 0):

Disable those checked boxes:

ReSharper | Options | Debugger | Editor Integration | DISABLE = Show local variable values
ReSharper | Options | Debugger | Editor Integration | DISABLE = Show current line expressions values.